# How to deep copy a struct that contains pointers?

Tags: c

Say my struct includes:

```
struct cat
{
 char *name;
 struct cat *breed;
 size_t n_kittens;
};
```

I believe memcpy does a shallow copy, so I've been trying to implement my own deep copy:

```
void deep_copy(struct cat *cat1, struct cat *cat2)
{
cat2->n_kittens = cat1->n_kittens;
cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
cat2->breed = (struct cat *)malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
cat2->breed = cat1->breed;
}
```

I also have a free function that I call before deep copying

```
void free(struct cat *cat)
{
free(cat->n_kittens);
free(cat->name);
free(cat->breed);
}
```

I keep getting a signal 11 error.
Am I deep copying correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What is `breed`? Is it an array, or a linked list, or something else?

Comment: Why would the breed be the same type as the cat?

Comment: Another issue is that your cats are cross-linked, and you need to be careful not to access cats you linked to through `breed` after deleting them. (It's essentially a problem solved by smart pointers in C++ or garbage collection in managed languages).

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), then you would need to deep-copy `cat1->breed` to `cat2->breed`. (why you have another cat in a cat -- instead of cat in a hat is unclear)

Comment: I think we need to see a [mcve], particularly a demonstration of how these structs are being created in the first place. You must create before you can copy.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1

**NOTE**: The following assumes that `breed` is not actually of type `struct cat` as currently shown in the question; rather it assumes a simple structure without pointers.

For deep copy, you'll want to replace:

```c
cat2->breed = cat1->breed;
```

with

```c
memcpy(cat2->breed, cat1->breed, sizeof(*cat2->breed));
```

Your current code simply copies the pointer, so the `breed` object being pointed to is the same and your `malloc` pointer is discarded.

---

### Solution 2

**NOTE**: the following assumes that `breed` is actually `litter`, and it is an array of `struct cat` with `n_kittens` elements.

```c
void deep_copy(struct cat *cat1, struct cat *cat2)
{
  cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
  cat2->litter = NULL;
  cat2->n_kittens = cat1->n_kittens;
  if (cat2->n_kittens > 0) {
    cat2->litter = (struct cat *)malloc(sizeof(struct cat)*cat2->n_kittens);
    // TODO add check for out-of-memory
    for(int kitten=0; kitten<cat2->n_kittens; ++kitten) {
      // recurse for each kitten
      deep_copy(cat1->litter+kitten, cat2->litter+kitten);
    }
  }
}
```

---

### `free()`

> I also have a free function that I call before deep copying

1. Your `free` function must have a name other than `free`, for instance `cat_free`
2. You do not want to call `cat_free` *before* deep copying.  One may call `free` only for pointers previously allocated by `malloc` and friends (`calloc`, `strdup`, etc).
3. Objects that are not referenced by pointer are not (individually) allocated and hence do not get `free`-d.
4. The `cat_free` should probably do a deep-free in order to avoid memory leaks.  A tool like `valgrind` is useful in empirically confirming that all allocated objects are released before program termination.

The above suggestions are incorporated below:

```c
void cat_free(struct cat *cat)
{
  if(cat != NULL) {
    free(cat->name);
    if(cat->litter != NULL) {
      for (int kitten=0; kitten<cat->n_kittens; ++kitten) {
        free(cat->litter+kitten);
      }
      free(cat->litter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `breed` might be list, in which case you will need to recursively copy the contents. It is not the your answer is wrong but it is too early to write it.

Comment: That's true, I'm expecting OP to change `breed` type to something other than `struct cat`.  I'll leave it as is for now, with a disclaimer.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you should check `cat1->breed != NULL` and only do the `malloc/memcpy` [to `cat2`] if the original is non-null.

Comment: @kiranBiradar If it is a list, how would you recursively copy it?

Comment: @CraigEstey that's a good point, you should post that in a separate answer.

Comment: I was working on an answer when your post showed up. But, the "quick on the trigger finger" downvote scared me off [I did +1 for you because I believe the DV was unwarranted]

Comment: @CraigEstey and kiran thanks, I incorporated your interpretation (code unverified)

Answer (score 1):

These lines don't do what you want:

```
cat2->breed = (struct cat *)malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
cat2->breed = cat1->breed;
```

The first allocates space for a new `struct cat`, but then the second line discards that pointer and copies the pointer from `cat1`, with the result that they are both pointing to the same structure.  When they both attempt to free the same storage, you get an error.

I would do the following:

```
void deep_copy(struct cat *cat1, struct cat *cat2)
{
    cat2->n_kittens = cat1->n_kittens;
    cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
    if (cat1->breed == NULL)
        cat2->breed = NULL;
    else {
        cat2->breed = malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
        if (cat2->breed == NULL) {
            // Do whatever recovery is appropriate here
            fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        deep_copy(cat1->breed, cat2->breed);
    }
}
```

Also, you can't name your `free` function `free`, since that will override the default `free`, making it uncallable.  So you want something like:

```
void my_free(struct cat *cat)
{
    free(cat->name);
    if (cat->breed != NULL) {
        my_free(cat->breed);
    }
    free(cat);
}
```

Note that I added a call to `free(cat);` on the assumption that your top-level `cat` was allocated by `malloc` and needs to be freed as well.  If that is not the case, then you can move the call into the preceding `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to others posts, You have to malloc `cat2->breed`, but only if `cat1->breed` is non-null

---

Here's a slightly corrected version:

```
void
deep_copy(struct cat *cat1, struct cat *cat2)
{
    cat2->n_kittens = cat1->n_kittens;
#if 0
    cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
#else
    if (cat1->name != NULL)
        cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
    else
        cat2->name = NULL;
#endif

#if 0
    cat2->breed = malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
    cat2->breed = cat1->breed;
#else
    if (cat1->breed != NULL) {
        cat2->breed = malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
        memcpy(cat2->breed,cat1->breed,sizeof(struct cat));
    }
    else
        cat2->breed = NULL;
#endif
}
```

---

**But**, I don't think that actually copies the `breed`, so we need to be recursive but still keep the `memcpy`:

```
void
deep_copy2(struct cat *cat1, struct cat *cat2)
{
    cat2->n_kittens = cat1->n_kittens;

    if (cat1->name != NULL)
        cat2->name = strdup(cat1->name);
    else
        cat2->name = NULL;

    if (cat1->breed != NULL) {
        cat2->breed = malloc(sizeof(struct cat));
        deep_copy2(cat2->breed,cat1->breed);
        memcpy(cat2->breed,cat1->breed,sizeof(struct cat));
    }
    else
        cat2->breed = NULL;
}
```

---

But, I really think refactoring the calling convention of the function makes it a bit simpler [similar to `strdup`]:

```
struct cat *
cat_dup(struct cat *catold)
{
    struct cat *catnew = calloc(1,sizeof(struct cat));

    catnew->n_kittens = catold->n_kittens;

    if (catold->name != NULL)
        catnew->name = strdup(catold->name);

    if (catold->breed != NULL)
        catnew->breed = cat_dup(catold->breed);

    return catnew;
}
```